# How to change navigation menu based on navigated route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I am trying to display different header menus depending on route change. For now what I have works well only if route is refreshed. How ever if you click on link from one page to another without page refresh, the changes don't take place.

Here is my app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

  isHeader: boolean;

  title = 'app works!';


  progress: number = 0;
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  name: string;

  constructor(private titleService: Title, af: AngularFire, private _r: Router) {

     this.name = 'Angular2'

     this._r.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        console.log('navigated to:', event.url);
        console.log('route state', event.state);
        console.log('');

      }
      else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // if u dont need the state, you could even use this event-type..
        console.log('navigated to:', event.urlAfterRedirects);
        if(event.urlAfterRedirects === '/home'){
          console.log("this is home");
          this.isHeader = true;
        }
      }
    });

  }
```

And here is my app.component.html

```
<!--*ngIf="!isHeader"-->
<div *ngIf="isHeader">
  Navigation just for the home route if route end  === /home
</div>

<div *ngIf="!isHeader">
  navigation for other routes but not the homepage
</div>
```

I get the navigated route and if it matches /home I change the header. This works only if there is a route refresh but navigating directly, it maintain the already state.

```
if(event.urlAfterRedirects === '/home'){
     console.log("this is home");
     this.isHeader = true;
  }
```

Comment: did it hit the `console.log`?

Comment: I get the routes correctly in the console on route change.